# curl - What timeout does PROTOCONNECT fall under

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

When using curl, which of the timeouts does the PROTOCONNECT stage fall under? If I try to SFTP to a nonstandard port that is open (but not an SFTP server), it seems to default to 300 seconds and am unsure of which timeout should be affecting this.

**EDIT:** was using an older version of libcurl and changing the connect timeout had no effect, Updated libcurl and the issue looks to have been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PROTOCONNECT` is the name of an internal state in libcurl and is a pre-connect state. Thus, it is controlled by both the connect and the general timeouts.